What are the functions obtained by complex polynomials evaluated at complex numbers
Given a complex polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, we can induce a function $ev_{\mathbb{C}}f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, x \mapsto ev(c)(f)$, where ev stands fpr evaluation. Denote the set of all such evaluated function as $EV_{\mathbb{C}[x]}^{\mathbb{C}}$For any function $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, it naturally induces an unique function $\overline{g}: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, namely, by separating out the real and imaginary part. Now applying it to functions in $EV^{\mathbb{C}}_{\mathbb{C}[x]}$, we can basically obtain a map $h: EV^{\mathbb{C}}_{\mathbb{C}[x]} \to \mathbb{R}[x_{1},x_{2}] \times \mathbb{R}[x_{1},x_{2}]$.
Intuitively, if we write out the complex polynomial, replace $x$ by $x_{1} +x_{2}i$, and expand it out, we obtain a polynomial in the form of $f_{1}+f_{2}i$, where $f_{1},f_{2} \in \mathbb{R}[x_{1},x_{2}]$

So I wonder what property does $h$ hold. In particular, is it surjective? I felt it is not, but I cannot prove that there exists a concrete example.

I'm just thinking about this when learning some basics about algebraic geometry. I'm not very familiar with complex analysis, so please be forgiving if this is a stupid question. Also, feel free to modify my notation, I made them up.

Is $x \mapsto ev(c)(f)$ a typo? I can't understand what $c$ is.

No, $h$ is not surjective. If $(p_1(x_1,x_2),p_2(x_1,x_2))$ is in the range of $h$, then, for some polynomial function $p(z)\in\Bbb C[z]$, $p_1(x_1,x_2)=\operatorname{Re}(p(x_1+x_2i))$ and $p_2(x_1,x_2)=\operatorname{Im}(p(x_1+x_2i))$. But then, by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, $\frac\partial{\partial x_1}p_1=\frac\partial{\partial x_2}p_2$ and $\frac\partial{\partial x_2}p_1=-\frac\partial{\partial x_1}p_2$. So, for instance, if you take $p_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ and $p_2(x_1,x_2)=0$, then $(p_1(x_1,x_2),p_2(x_1,x_2))$ is not in the range of $h$.

Your title question has a useful positive answer if you are willing to bypass your attempted method.
In brief, $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a polynomial if and only if it is differentiable at each point of $\mathbb C$ and at infinity!
To make sense out of this silly statement, we have to set up some notation. Consider the so-called "extended complex plane" $\mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ (also known as the Riemann sphere). We can define the extended function $f^* : \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb C^*$ by the formula
$$f^*(z) = \begin{cases}
f(z) & \quad\text{if $z \in \mathbb C$} \\
\infty &\quad\text{if $z = \infty$}
\end{cases}
$$
Now we want to change coordinates, rewriting the function $f^*$ using the "multiplicative inverse coordinate" $w = z^{-1}$ in both the domain and the codomain. Multiplicative inversion is usually defined, of course, only for $\mathbb C - \{0\}$. But we can extend  it to all of $\mathbb C^*$ by setting $0^{-1}=\infty$ and $\infty^{-1}=0$.
Changing coordinates, we obtain the function $F : \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb C^*$ defined by the formula
$$F(w) = (f^*(w^{-1}))^{-1}
$$
and note that $F(0)=0$.
With this notation, the function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a polynomial if and only if its complex derivative $f'(z)$ exists at each $z \in \mathbb C$, and the function $F$ satisfies the following property:

There exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb C$ such that $0 \in U$ and $F(U) \subset \mathbb C$ and the complex derivative $F'(0)$ exists.


Incidentally, the proof of forward direction of this equivalence runs in parallel to one of the proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra. If $f(z)$ is a polynomial function of degree $d$ then from the formula for $F(w)$ one shows that $F(0)$ is a zero of order $d$. From this conclusion one can immediately obtain the property of $F$ written above. Also, from this conclusion one can continue on, using some differential topology, to conclude that $f$ has exactly $d$ zeroes counted with multiplicity.
